# MYSQL takes 100% of CPU. Slow queries

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm not sure why, but the MYSQL gives a very big load on cpu. 
I have to update the database multiple times per second and the user base is growing.

It was fine at first, but CPU load increased every day and now

Here is the slow query from log:

```
*Query_time: 4.182654  Lock_time: 0.000070 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1315908025;
UPDATE Stats SET Time = 1315908020 WHERE Domain = 'facebook.com';*
```

why would such a query be so slow? 
Does slow queries take more CPU?

Could this be because I have chosen the wrong types for rows?

```
time: int (11), Domain VARCHAR (1000)
```

Stats table have 13k rows and growing.

Comment: What's the table engine and how many times per second is the table accessed?

Comment: Please provide the DDL of the table.

Comment: DNS names are restricted to 253 characters; you might save a bit of space there.

Comment: I'm not sure how many times per second is the table accessed. Probably like 10+ times. What is DDL? I use PHP & MYSQL.

Comment: DDL= Data Description Language. Or in simple terms what you would type to create the table structure. CREATE TABLE stats (time int(11), domain varchar(1000),...indexes and things )

Comment: How many rows did it update? Updating lots of rows can be expensive.

Comment: "Rows_sent: 0" is rather suspicious in that respect. But a quick Google search told me that queries can also get in the slow query log if there's no appropriate index. (see `--log-queries-not-using-indexes`) Considering the comment on my answer, I'm also going to bet that this wasn't a prepared query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common reason for slow queries is the lack of an index. MySQL has to find the row `WHERE Domain='facebook.com'`. Is that a table scan, or an index lookup?

Comment: 13k table scan should still take a fraction of second unless it's getting scanned several hundreds of times per second or more. It's most likely the lack of index on the mentioned column, but more than that it seems like misconfiguration of the storage engine too.

Comment: I'm  not sure what's the difference between table scan and index lookup.

Comment: A table scan basically means that MySQL has to look at each record in turn. An index lookup means that there is an ordered list that can be searched in a type of binary tree fashion - much faster.

Comment: I don't have an index. I have searched info around it and not having index is probably causing the load.

Comment: Please don't encourage the use of double quotes to surround literal SQL strings - it's WRONG according to ANSI and only works in MySQL because it is not ANSI compatible.

Comment: My bad, no idea how those got in.